# Discrepancy in frequency response of biquad filter (in Python)

Tags: audio, infinite-impulse-response, transfer-function, biquad

I have written a simple biquad filter class but when I check its frequency response, I get different results with different methods.  If I check it "empirically" (by taking the FFT of its impulse response) then I get the expected results.  However, when I check it "analytically" (by plugging coefficients into the transfer function) then the graphs do not align.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?  I have tried several different equations for plotting the magnitude response of the transfer function (including [here](https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Analysis/186-frequency-response-from-biquad-coefficients.html)) and they all agree with each other, but none of them align with the "correct" response given by the impulse response.

[image: Output of code below]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12,6)

# RBJ biquad peaking filter
class Filter:
    def __init__(self, fs, freq, gain, Q):
        
        self.fs = fs
        self.freq = freq
        self.gain = gain
        self.Q = Q
        
        (self.b0, 
         self.b1, 
         self.b2, 
         self.a1, 
         self.a2) = get_coefficients(fs, freq, gain, Q)
        
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.xmem1 = 0
        self.xmem2 = 0
        self.ymem1 = 0
        self.ymem2 = 0    
    
    def process(self, x):
        y = (self.b0 * x +
             self.b1 * self.xmem1 +
             self.b2 * self.xmem2 -
             self.a1 * self.ymem1 -
             self.a2 * self.ymem2)
        
        self.xmem2 = self.xmem1
        self.xmem1 = x
        self.ymem2 = self.ymem1
        self.ymem1 = y        
        return y    
    
    def __call__(self, xs):
        self.reset()
        ys = np.zeros(len(xs))
        for i, x in enumerate(xs):
            ys[i] = self.process(x)
        return ys   
    

def get_coefficients(fs, freq, gain, Q):     
    A = np.power(10, gain/40)
    w0 = 2 * np.pi * freq / fs
    cos_w0 = np.cos(w0)
    sin_w0 = np.sin(w0)
    alpha = sin_w0 / (2 * Q)
    
    b0 =   1 + alpha*A
    b1 =  -2 * cos_w0
    b2 =   1 - alpha*A
    a0 =   1 + alpha/A
    a1 =  -2 * cos_w0
    a2 =   1 - alpha/A
        
    # normalize
    coefficients = np.array([b0, b1, b2, a1, a2]) / a0
    return coefficients.tolist()


def get_empirical_response(filt):
    impulse = np.zeros(filt.fs)
    impulse[0] = 1.
    ir = filt(impulse)
    X = np.fft.rfft(ir)
    return 20*np.log10(np.abs(X))[1:]


def get_analytic_response(filt):
    freqs = np.arange(1, filt.fs//2+1)
    w = 2*np.pi / freqs    
    z1 = np.exp(-1j * w)
    z2 = np.exp(-2j * w)
    H_z = ( (filt.b0 + filt.b1*z1 + filt.b2*z2) /
            (      1 + filt.a1*z1 + filt.a2*z2) )
    return 20*np.log10(np.abs(H_z))

fs   = 48_000
freq = 200
gain = -6
Q    = 0.707
filt = Filter(fs, freq, gain, Q)

freqs = np.arange(1, fs//2+1)
empirical_response = get_empirical_response(filt)
analytic_response = get_analytic_response(filt)

plt.plot(freqs, empirical_response, label='empirical response')
plt.plot(freqs, analytic_response, label='analytic response')
plt.title(f'Frequency Response of {gain} db at {freq} Hz')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude (db)')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you change line `w = 2*np.pi / freqs` found in **get_analytic_response(filt)** to `w = 2*np.pi*freqs/fs`  it gives exactly same response for both .

Comment: @JuhaP thank you! Yep that line is what was screwing things up. `np.linspace` also works.